# Locking a footer to the bottom of my content wrapper

Tags: html, css, footer

So as the title states, Trying to lock this footer at the bottom of the content wrapper.
Everything I've read says use bottom 0, but that locks it to the bottom of the window not the div surrounding my page. Any suggestions appreciated, thanks a bunch.
HTML

```
<div id='contentwrapper'>
  (theres stuff in here but it's negligible for now)
  <div id='footer'>
  <div id='footertext'>
  Blahblahblahblahblah
  </div>
  <div id='footerlogo'>
  <img src='companylogo.png' height='80px'>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#footertext{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 right:0
 }
 #footerlogo{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 }
 #footer{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 z-index:300;
 text-align:right;
 width:800px;
 //padding-top:5px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 min-height:40px;
 color:black;
 background: rgb(173, 194, 255); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't support rgba */
 background: rgba(173, 194, 255, .3);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your content wrapper has a postion: relative set on it, otherwise the absolutely positioned element has nothing to go off of.

Comment: it should be relative by default but I will add it and see what happens

Comment: The default value for position is static. Absolutely positioned elements look for the first ancestor with a position set to anything other than static. Glad I could help.